# Dividing class file into partial classes affects scope?

Tags: c#, scope, partial-classes

I have a class library project, and my namespace/main class looks like this:

File: Document.cs

```
     namespace HtmlEngine 
     {

         public class Document : IDisposable
         { ...

               public class DocumentActionReplaceByTag : IDocumentAction
               {
```

All of this works fine, and in another project/assembly I put:

```
using HtmlEngine;

...

DocumentActionReplaceByTag currentDocAction = new HtmlEngine.DocumentActionReplaceByTag("[NEXT_PART]");
```

and it works perfectly.  However, I've now divided that Document class file into several files, called DocumentActions.cs, DocumentSections.cs, as well as keeping the main functionality in my Document.cs file.  At the top of each of these I put:

```
public partial class Document : IDisposable
{
```

Now, in the consuming project I get a 'cannot resolve symbol 'DocumentActionReplaceByTag'' error.  I still have my using reference to HtmlEngine.

The closest thing on the 'net I could find was this post which describes my plight similarly, but he wasn't very clear about the reasons for it happening: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/140673/understanding-partial-classes

I have always believed partial classes were syntactic sugar and they were combined into a single class prior to compilation.  I repeated the interface for each partial class declaration, not sure if that could be a factor.

Why would this now be out of scope?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your code correctrly the line for creating new DocumentActionReplaceByTag must look like:

```
DocumentActionReplaceByTag currentDocAction = new HtmlEngine.Document.DocumentActionReplaceByTag("[NEXT_PART]");
```

And what about IDisposable, it must be specified only in one partial file.

Glinkot, from provided code I see that your DocumentActionReplaceByTag class is put into Document class. The folowing sample shows that Nested classes always accessable via ParentClass.NestedClass (note that all my classes are in same file and code not compiles)

```
    namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class ParentClass
    {
        public class NestedClass { }

                public void SomeMethod()
                {
                    // This compiles, since nested class is used inside parent class
                    NestedClass nestedClass = new NestedClass();
                }
    }

    public class AnotherClass
    {
        public AnotherClass()
        {
            // Not compiles since "NestedClass" is defined as nested class
            var nestedClass = new NestedClass();
            // Will compiles
            var nestedClass = new ParentClass.NestedClass();

            // Not compiles since "NestedClass" is defined as nested class
            NestedClass nestedClass = new NestedClass();
            // Will compiles
            ParentClass.NestedClass nestedClass = new ParentClass.NestedClass();
        }
    }
}
```

If you have another situation then please provide more details.

Comment: Thanks Andris.  That's correct, adding the explicit reference does the job but I would like to continue accessing DocumentActionReplaceByTag without the prefix.  This was how it worked prior to dividing the class up.  I did remove IDisposable from the other files but still this made no difference.  I cant add "using HtmlEngin.Document" as this isn't a namespace - my question is why is it behaving differently (and hopefully, what can I do to resolve it).  Thx

Comment: I add example, with using of nested classes. Please provide more details if you feel that I didn't understand your situation.

Comment: Hi Andris.  In this case (see desc in original question) I'm using the class from a different assembly/namespace.  The nested class could be instantiated without qualification when the classes were in a single file, and yet when I divide it into partial classes this no longer works!  As per the guy's description in the link on my question.  I don't understand why I'd then need to qualify each with parentclass.  I'll just need to recombine the class if it comes down to that, and use regions.  Maybe that's better anyway, but I still wonder why the scope change happens.